# Hard drive detected but not showing up in device and drives in computer

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Recently when I tried to open a video file from my external hard drive, the explorer menu started to become 'not responding' and later, it stopped showing up in device and drives from My computer.

It seems that the power indicator LED is not flashing nor showing any response. However, it seems to be detected in device and printers. The Drive's properties says that it is working properly. The pop up menu which usually opens when the drive is connected no longer pops up.

My laptop was on Window 8 Pro and I have tested the drive on various devices including a desktop with a Linux Mint installed on it. The external Hard drive is a Seagate Backup Plus Portable Drive.

Although google searches says that I should replace the cable, I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try using a different USB cable first, @Htetmyat Aung! If the behavior of the external HDD doesn't improve, I'd strongly recommend you to refer to the HDD manufacturer's website and download their diagnostic tool to check up on the health and SMART status of the drive. Keep in mind that you'd need to run the short and the long test.

I'd also suggest you to backup any important data from that hard drive before proceeding with the troubleshooting. It's highly possible that it could be going bad.

I'd also check the warranty. If it's still covered, you might be able to RMA it and get a replacement from the manufacturer's customer support.

Good luck! Hope I was helpful! 
Happy Holidays! :)